# German way of gesturing 3 in Inglourious Basterds?

Tags: plot-explanation, inglourious-basterds

How true is that., when i googled I don't find much info about that. Is that made up for film or do Germans gesture like that.

Comment: Mmm - its not exactly a duplicate, but this is pretty clear from the answer to this question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11178/how-could-lt-hicox-fluently-speak-german-and-then-give-himself-away-by-using-th

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

Sources:

- I am German myself and this is not a regionalism.
- [Wikipedia says so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_counting).

For future exploration about subtle differences:

- Different systems to tell the time within Germany (expect passionate discussions about why the cake method is or is not the right one).

Comment: I have read the question and the answer several times, and I still have no idea what is being asked, or why the answer is correct. :p

Comment: @JohnP Have you seen the movie? It should be obvious then.

Comment: @JohnP The question asks if it is true that Germans hold up three different fingers than US Americans when they want to indicate the number "3". Being German myself, I can confirm his's answer. ;)

Comment: @magnattic: Being German myself, I consider this claim to be false. It is true that when *counting*, Germans are likely (though not guaranteed) to start with the thumb. However, for indicating a single number, it's mainly the total number of fingers that's relevant, and both thumb-index-middle and index-middle-ring seem equally common and natural to me. But maybe things were still different in the days of WW2?