# What about the drink order alerted Major Hellstrom?

Tags: character, inglourious-basterds

In the 2009 film [**Inglorious Basterds**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglourious_Basterds), British intelligence agent Archie Hicox is meeting a German spy in a tavern, but his unusual accent catches the attention of Gestapo officer Major Dieter Hellstrom. The two banter back and forth for several minutes, with Hellstrom attempting to catch Hicox in a lie. Finally, Hellstrom orders a bottle of scotch and asks Hicox how many glasses. Hicox orders three glasses, saying "Drei glasse", and holding up three fingers as he does so. After the drinks are delivered,

> Hellstrom pulls his pistol under the table and states that Hicox just gave himself away. leading to a fast-paced shootout scene.

As far as I can tell, Hicox's use of German was correct, so I'm thinking perhaps the gesture of three fingers was behind the Major's behavior. After repeated viewings, however, the answer still eludes me.

**What about the drink order alerted Major Hellstrom?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could Lt. Hicox fluently speak German and then give himself away by using the wrong gesture?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11178/how-could-lt-hicox-fluently-speak-german-and-then-give-himself-away-by-using-th)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the other answer states, it's about differences of which fingers to hold up when indicating the number 3.

Repeated viewings of the Bar scene would tell you nothing unless you happened to know this cultural difference.  However it *is* explained in the very next scene when Lieutenant Aldo interrogates Bridget von Hammersmark, when they are treating her for the bullet wound to her leg.

```
BRIDGET
The English man, gave himself away.

LT. ALDO
How did he do that?

BRIDGET
He ordered three glasses.
(She holds up three fingers, index to ring)

BRIDGET
We order, three glasses.
(She holds up three fingers, thumb to middle)

BRIDGET
That's the German three. The other
is odd. Germans would, and did notice it.
```

Comment: I must have got up for a drink or something - completely missed that scene. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hicox used index, middle and ring fingers to signify three.  *Whoops*.

[The German/continental way](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger-counting#Western_world) is to use index finger, middle finger and thumb.

Comment: The German way is also *American* Sign Language usage.  Thumb touching little finger means 6, not 3, in ASL.